# Representing Axiom of Union in First Order Set Theory

Tags: elementary-set-theory

When representing the union axiom in first order set theory, the most common representation is

$\forall a \exists c \forall x (x \in c \longleftrightarrow \exists b (b \in a \land x\in b)) $.

I was wondering if this representation could also be considered correct:

$ \forall a \forall b \exists c \forall x (x \in c \longleftrightarrow x\in a \lor x \in b) $.

Is my logic flawed? I can't really wrap my head around the first representation.

Comment: They are both wrong, including the one you call "the most common representation" of the union axiom. Did you really find that in some book? Are you sure you copied it correctly? That last $\forall$ wasn't a $\exists$?

Comment: Why does the title refer to the axiom of choice, while the body refers to the axiom of union? In any case, your second formulation asserts that for any *two* sets $a$ and $b$, their union $a\cup b$ exists. This is not what the axiom of union says!